# How can I completely reset wifi settings?

Tags: 14.04, networking, wireless, reset

I know this question has been asked before and I have yet to find an answer. Is there a way to completely reset wifi or networking settings of ubuntu 14.04 LTS? I want to reset them, not fix an issue I have.

Comment: What do you mean exactly with reset?

Comment: What kind of changes you've made to your settings ?

Comment: @A.B. Reset the settings to default, purge all changes made, remove saved connections. Serg - There are a ton of connections saved and it was used for a hotspot. The wifi connections turns off and hotspot appears randomly without me doing anything. Also the connection is slow.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To remove your connections from Network Manager run:

```
sudo rm -f /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/*; sudo pkill -9 NetworkManager
```

Just make sure you have passwords for wifi networks that you intend to use before you do so.

Comment: Just a thought: First the kill command and then delete the configuration?

Comment: What would this order achieve here? I want to remove all connections and have Network Manager re-read its configuration. Killing NM before altering its configuration is a no-op.

Comment: You're welcome, good luck!

Comment: Saved my Ass. I was struggling with this freaking wifi issue for days. And this works a 100%. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To delete all connections avaliable to NetworkManager:

`echo $( nmcli -t -f UUID con list  ) | xargs -n 1 nmcli con delete uuid`

(this lists all UUIDs of connections and one by one removes deletes each connection, similar in effect to Marcin's answer , only no need for sudo access)

To reinstall NetworkManager

`sudo apt-get --reinstall install NetworkManager`

Comment: `Error: argument 'list' not understood.`